# Using Pi 3 Bluetooth with external GPS

Tags: pi-3, serial, bluetooth, gps, jessie-lite

Im trying to connect a RPI3 (running jessie-lite) via Bluetooth to an android phones gps output. I'm using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meowsbox.btgps to stream NMEA strings from my phone.

The end game is to stream positioning strings from a dedicated GPS to the Pi and store them using python.

The problem(s) i'm having are:

I can scan, pair and trust my phone from within bluetoothctl however when i then try connect i get an error.

```
[bluetooth]# pair F8:95:C7:17:AF:66
Attempting to pair with F8:95:C7:17:AF:66
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 Modalias: bluetooth:v00C4p13A1d1000
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 7fbe865e-518b-462a-b31b-90acf6a472fc
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: 936da01f-9abd-4d9d-80c7-02af85c822a8
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 UUIDs: e3cccccd-33b7-457d-a03c-aa1c54bf617f
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device F8:95:C7:17:AF:66 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect F8:95:C7:17:AF:66
Attempting to connect to F8:95:C7:17:AF:66
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I've followed instructions from:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=919420#p919420
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=140631

Without any success, using rfcomm bind allows me to connect to the pi using a bluetooth terminal app on android but won't let me connect to the nmea stream.

If anyone has any other ideas to try i'd be incredibly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/) announcement is still up to date, but according to it Raspbian only supports bluetooth HID devices (read: keyboards and mice) and audio sinks (read: headsets and speakers).